# understanding Kafka end offset and committed offset

Tags: python, apache-kafka, offset

I want to fetch Kafka topic's committed offset and end offset (position) using Pyhon and Kafka client,

and I'm wondering why the offset is received by topic + consumer-group itself (`KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets(consumer_group)`)

while the position is received by a consumer + topic's partitioned (`KafkaConsumer.end_offsets(partitions)`).

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the quetion, but both calls return in a way the same information, but for a potential different number of partitions. So both are used in different scenarios.

With [`list_consumer_group_offsets(group_id, group_coordinator_id=None, partitions=None)`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets) you can also limit the return for a set of partitions rather than all of them. Basically this call has no context, so the consumer group needs to be passed as a parameter.

KafkaConsumer has an consumer group and topics which are passed on construction. The difference with the other call is that this filter only the topics the specific consumer is consuming from.

Again, both return very similar data, but each is useful in different scenarios.

The python docs are quite clear, but you must understand how kafka works internally as it is a bit of a complex beast. The API won't make it clear in any way how kafka is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `committed` comes only when there is a *consumer group*. So the very point that you are asking for the committed offsets means that there is a *consumer group*. The consumer group contains the details of the topics and its partitions.

However, `end offsets` term is used regardless of whether there is a consumer group or not. This is the reason why the function is written to accept the list of topic partitions.

---

Sometimes it might not be needed to use a *consumer group* but we just want to see what is in the topic. In this case, we don't create a consumer group, we just rather *assign* the topic(s) to the consumer and just read them, like we use `kafka-console-consumer` for.

For example, we use the `kafka-console-consumer` for reading the last *n* messages or displaying the topic information.